# Xbox Application Development using C# and Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, xbox360, xbox

I have been investigating into application (not games) development on Xbox but i could not find any help or tutorial which i could use as a starting point for my project like a basic template.

I have an Xbox Live Account which i know is needed for app submission.

I have gone through alot of links like [this](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-us/home/getting_started)

But it doesnt provide help on following points like :

1.Which IDE to use (does VS 2012 for Windows Phone or for Windows 8 work?)

2.is C# the language to use(i would prefer to use this)

3.Any basic starter app/template (with newest SDK, as i have seen a few samples they fail to load)

Any help would be largely appreciated

Comment: I would suggest using XNA with Visual Studio, but as far as I know microsoft are scrapping XNA soon enough. Not sure whats being brought in to replace it

Comment: The Xbox app development SDK is not available/public now, only XNA but it is for games...

Comment: @RicoSuter i see, but then do you mean to say that there is no way i can develop apps for Xbox ?

Comment: @Paddyd OK but even if i use XNA i am not sure where to get started.Can you help on that like some basic/starter app

Comment: As Rico Suter said, it is for games, but this will get you started
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203893.aspx

Comment: At the moment you cannot simply publish apps or games like in windows phone or win8, you have to be an approved developer... Public app sdk is announced for xbox one but not released yet

Comment: @RicoSuter alright but can we not even start developing ? using the public sdk

Comment: See http://www.xbox.com/en-US/developers/faq and http://www.xbox.com/en-us/Developers/id

Answer (score 2):

You can't develop Apps for Xbox (360 or one) with the public SDK (XNA).
Xna allows you to create video game for the indie market only.

To be able to create video game for XBLA market or apps store, you need to be a official video game editor/compagny and in partnership with Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studios seems to be what most developers would use for xbox.
As for languages if your looking to develop apps for xbox and not games, you could use C# or WPF.
Hope this was a bit helpful.

Comment: I have VS2012 but it doesnt have any template which says *XNA Apps* but it does have template for *XNA Game Dev*

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a public SDK yet, but it sounds like Windows 8 apps will be portable to Xbox One at some point in the future: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20222083/867611