# Developing apps for Xbox One?

Tags: windows-8, xbox, xbox-one

I've heard that Xbox One application development is quite similar to Windows 8, but I haven't found much to suggest why, or what differences there are.

Is there any documentation about creating Xbox One applications (not games, apps.. like Netflix, etc), or even how to apply to obtain such information?

Comment: Any luck with this in the end? I am finding it hard to find any information regarding Xbox App development even now - 10 months on.

Comment: I have this same question in 2018 -- Looks like the only options for new Xbox developers are UWP or Unity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Important update on this topic:**

Every Xbox One is now capable of going into developer mode via the Xbox Dev Mode App. Games and more importantly apps can now be developed by anyone.

FAQ on this topic: http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/apps/developer-mode-activation-app-faq

Answer (score 14):

I've been trying to find more details myself. It sounds like the ability to develop apps is coming:

http://arstechnica.com/gaming/2013/10/wait-can-the-xbox-one-really-run-generalized-windows-8-apps/

> Nothing to announce today, but when I talk about that common core,
> you're seeing that common core in action, being able to target other
> devices over time that run the Windows 8 engine.
>
> If you want to know about how to get a head start about thinking about
> developing for Xbox One, **the logical thing to do is [to] go build
> Windows 8 applications**.

There are some additions in WinRT designed to allow interaction with Kinect:

http://www.oxm.co.uk/59024/features/what-its-actually-like-to-develop-for-xbox-one-microsoft-explains/?page=2

> The applications are very similar to Windows 8, like we brought a lot
> of the Windows 8 namespace - WinRT can be used for building those
> applications, the time it takes to port a Windows 8 application to the
> new Xbox? It's super, super easy. There's some things we added to the
> platform for handling gestures, for handling voice and handling ten
> foot UI paradigms.

Right now it appears the most you can do is try out your app ideas in WinRT and wait until an Xbox One SDK appears.

Comment: @Domecraft - just got the association bonus. Thank you for restoring the balance of karma :-)

Comment: Another option might be to build a web based app and display it through IE - you can pin web pages to the dashboard and you should be able to snap IE if you're interested in that functionality.

Comment: Just announced at Build: http://www.engadget.com/2014/04/02/universal-windows-apps-on-xbox/

Answer (score 6):

I've worked on a few of the launch apps for Xbox One. Unfortunately, you cannot get an app on the platform unless you've been invited (at this point in time), however rumour has it that MS may open up the platform a bit more in the next year or two.

All documentation and information regarding the development itself is all under strict NDA, so it's highly unlikely that you'll find any in depth details.

If you're interested, you can always try contacting the Xbox team for more information.

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft currently does not have any official documentation for Xbox One Apps, however it seems that if you go here: http://www.xbox.com/en-us/Developers/id You can register to become a developer for the Xbox One and get the development kit so you can develop apps for it.

Main information about developing for the Xbox can be found at http://www.xbox.com/en-US/developers, which includes how to register for an Xbox One development Kit
 and the different tools and middleware that can be used to create games/apps for the Xbox. More documentation for the Xbox One will most likely get published by the end of this year.

To add to what I said, I recommend creating apps for the windows phones as it will show Microsoft that you can successfully build apps for their products. If your app gets enough downloads they will probably allow you to create an app for the Xbox One because you already have a track history

Comment: "we are looking for professional independent game developers who have a proven track record of shipping games on console, PC, mobile, or tablet. " yea, except for I'm talking about apps, not games :/ Seems like unless Microsoft calls you first for apps, there is no way to get into the ecosystem right now

Answer (score 0):

You could use Unity because it can use cross-platforms like Xbox, iPad, iPhone, PS4 and more. Also you can create 3D and 2D apps for development and to upload it to the phone you can use Xcode to build and run the unity project on the phone. If you get stuck you can always go to https://unity3d.com.